# In matplotlib, is there a method to fix or arrange the order of x-values of a mixed type with a character and digits?

Tags: matplotlib, x-axis

There are several Q/A for x-values in matplotlib and it shows when the x values are int or float, matploblit plots the figure in the right order of x. For example, in character type, the plot shows x values in the order of

```
1 15 17 2 21 7 etc
```

but when it became int, it becomes

```
1 2 7 15 17 21 etc
```

in human order.
If the x values are mixed with character and digits such as

```
NN8 NN10 NN15 NN20 NN22 etc
```

the plot will show in the order of

```
NN10 NN15 NN20 NN22 NN8 etc
```

Is there a way to fix the order of x values in the human order or the existing order in the x list without removing 'NN' in x-values.

In more detail, the xvalues are directory names and using grep sort inside  linux function, the results are displayed in linux terminal as follows, which can be saved in text file.

```
joonho@login:~/NDataNpowN$ get_TEFrmse NN 2 | sort -n -t N -k 3
NN7 0.3311
NN8 0.3221
NN9 0.2457
NN10 0.2462
NN12 0.2607
NN14 0.2635
```

Without sort, the linux shell also displays in the machine order such as

```
NN10 0.2462
NN12 0.2607
NN14 0.2635
NN7 0.3311
NN8 0.3221
NN9 0.2457
```

Comment: Will the numbers always be prefixed with "NN" or could it also be the list `ABC7, DE12, F34, GH114`?

Comment: The easiest way would be to read the text file into pandas (if pandas is an option), create an additional number column, sort the df by it, then plot the values. Should NN8-NN13-NN110 be evenly spaced or reflect the distance between numbers?

Comment: Both would be OK. But if it is spaced by the number, it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, pandas would make this task easier than dealing with base Python lists and such:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#imports the text file assuming that your data are separated by space, as in your example above
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace=True, names=["X", "Y"])
#extracting the number in a separate column, assuming you do not have terms like NN1B3X5
df["N"] = df.X.str.replace(r"\D", "", regex=True).astype(int)
#this step is only necessary, if your file is not pre-sorted by Linux
df = df.sort_values(by="N")

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 6))

#categorical plotting
df.plot(x="X", y="Y", ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Evenly spaced")

#numerical plotting
df.plot(x="N", y="Y", ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xticks(df.N)
ax2.set_xticklabels(df.X)
ax2.set_title("Numerical spacing")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Since you asked if there is a non-pandas solution - of course. Pandas makes some things just more convenient. In this case, I would revert to numpy. Numpy is a matplotlib dependency, so in contrast to pandas, it must be installed, if you use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re

#read file as strings
arr = np.genfromtxt("test.txt", dtype="U15")
#remove trailing strings
Xnums = np.asarray([re.sub(r"\D", "", i) for i in arr[:, 0]], dtype=int)
#sort array 
arr = arr[np.argsort(Xnums)]
#extract x-values as strings...
Xstr = arr[:, 0]
#...and y-values as float
Yvals = arr[:, 1].astype(float)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 6))

#categorical plotting
ax1.plot(Xstr, Yvals)
ax1.set_title("Evenly spaced")

#numerical plotting
ax2.plot(np.sort(Xnums), Yvals)
ax2.set_xticks(np.sort(Xnums))
ax2.set_xticklabels(Xstr)
ax2.set_title("Numerical spacing")

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Which line of the script makes it different from python for the order of x-values? Or is this pandas' nature? Does it draw just following the order of the data in df?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question correctly. Pandas does the same as base Python in terms of ordering. What we do here is to create a helper column `N` that extracts just the numbers with `str.replace(...)`, sort the dataframe according to this column, then use the new sorting order for plotting. If you plot directly the strings of `X` in the first case, the categorical data will be plotted and labeled against the index. In the second case, you have to specify that the ticks are set where the numbers of the data points are, then add the corresponding string labels.

Comment: The advantage of pandas is that it keeps your corresponding data in one row, so we avoid the problems to find the correct indexes of corresponding list elements. Pandas also offers some commonly used plotting routines guessing what your desired output is. They are built on top of matplotlib, so matplotlib standard graphs are easier to generate with this functionality.

Comment: I saw your now-deleted comment and have added a non-pandas approach to this problem.

Comment: As you said at first, coding with pandas is simple.

Comment: When I started learning Python, I was a bit hesitant to adopt numpy and pandas. Is the effort really worth learning this on top of Python? My answer today: Yes. Yes, it is. If one understood the basic principles of Python, working with these libraries is really easy. And they offer a plethory of possibilities to speed up or simplify things.